# live server extension does not reload when I save

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio-code, liveserver

I am a newbie. I download live server extension on VSCode to code HTML and CSS but it does not reload for me when I save file.

I tried to uninstall and download again but It doesn't still work. Pls help me to fix this problem

Comment: @Francesco Pippi i try to fix by your way but it doesn't still work

Answer (score 1):

a quick google search gave me this:
[https://lightrun.com/solutions/ritwickdey-vscode-live-server-live-server-not-reloading-automatically/#:~:text=Open%20the%20settings%2C%20search%20for,live%20server%20not%20reloading%20automatically](https://lightrun.com/solutions/ritwickdey-vscode-live-server-live-server-not-reloading-automatically/#:%7E:text=Open%20the%20settings%2C%20search%20for,live%20server%20not%20reloading%20automatically).

This may be what you need? I have noticed the same thing as well.

Comment: i did it but it doesn't still work

Answer (score -1):

When you use the live server extension, you need to start it using the "Go Live" button at the bottom right of the screen (where it shows the current line and column numbers).

When you start the server, a new browser window should pop up at the correct address and auto reload should work when you save the file(s).

Comment: i did it but it doesn't refresh when i save